# Unable to clone repo from gitlab into Oracle VirtualBox VM (CentOS) - host key verification failed

Tags: centos, virtualbox, git, ssh-keygen, gitlab

I am trying to clone a repo from gitlab into Oracle VirtualBox VM (CentOS) hosted on Win 10 machine.

Following are the steps:

1. generate key via `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and copy the key from generated id_rsa.pub file into gitlab > preferences > ssh keys
2. Run the following git command to clone the repo - but it fails with error "Host key verification failed" - on close observation `.ssh` dir that contains the `id_rsa` files does not contain `known_hosts` file

   ```
   $ git clone git@gitlab.<...>.git
   Cloning into '<repo>'...
   The authenticity of host 'gitlab.<...> (---.---.---.---)' can't be established.
   ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:.......
   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? y 
   Host key verification failed.
   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
   and the repository exists.
   $
   ```

Also - trying to delete any existing host file does not work

```
$ ssh-keygen -R <hostname>
do_known_hosts: hostkeys_foreach failed: No such file or directory
```

I am able to clone the same repo into Windows machine so there is no issue with repo's existence. Also, in other machines, cloning is successful.

Any leads on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try answering "yes" to the "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? " question, rather than hitting return?

Comment: I did press yes - corrected the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the issue was that in my PATH variable `/usr/bin` entry somehow preceded `usr/bin/git` - this was a duplicate entry along with the one at the end of the PATH variable - this caused the issue. Learnt another way of not causing a mistake.